# CSV file with non-English characters error in postman and angular http request

Tags: angular, csv, utf-8, http-headers, postman

I have uploaded a CSV file with some german words. I can access the file via [this link](https://selisefalcon.blob.core.windows.net/ecap-falcon/dev/9B4C6EBB-DF5F-4B83-9D48-E32D4036A244/fb3591f8-d6e5-4403-afc8-8b6997257885/78a36cc8-89f5-47ff-90e6-6c3e14c6f6d5/test.csv?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=GSqdz6QcDWPI7C0rO6o7p5lXXwGOLLuRsDTVf36q68E%3D&se=2022-05-07T03%3A28%3A51Z&sp=r)  . When I try to get the file via postman, the response is not fully utf converted.
[image]

After downloading the file, I open the file with excel or notepad++ I get the expected result.
[image]

Again I try to get the file via angular HttpClient. I get this response in Chrome's network preview section.
[image]

But when I console.log the response, Now the response is incorrect.
[image]

I try to add `Accept: application/csv` and `Accept-Charset: UTF-8` header with postman call, But get same result.

I make a  [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-csv-file-kwrx9s?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the "responseType" to "arraybuffer" and then decode the array with whatever encoding you need. In this case the `iso-8859-2`

look at the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-csv-file-ee1nj2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Since a byte can only have 256 distinct values, and the set of all the world's languages ​​is more than 256 characters, UTF-8 needs to use more than one byte to represent some characters. In general, accented characters like the word “bênção” are represented as 2 bytes in UTF-8 (as opposed to just 1 in ISO 8859-1):

```
             b |    ê   |  n |    ç   |    ã   |  o
ISO 8859-1: 62 |   EA   | 6E |   E7   |   E3   | 6F
     UTF-8: 62 | C3  AA | 6E | C3  A7 | C3  A3 | 6F
```

This is a problem when you try to read text written in one encoding as if it were another encoding: if the text was written as UTF-8 but read as ISO 8859-1, it appears as “bÃªnÃ§Ã£o”; the opposite appears as “b�n��o”

example in JavaScript:

```js
var bytesUtf8 = new Uint8Array([0x62, 0xc3, 0xaa, 0x6e, 0xc3, 0xa7, 0xc3, 0xa3, 0x6f]);
var bytesIso = new Uint8Array([0x62, 0xea, 0x6e, 0xe7, 0xe3, 0x6f]);
var decIso = new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1")
var decUtf8 = new TextDecoder("utf-8")
var decBytesIsoCorrect = decIso.decode(bytesIso)
var decBytesUtf8Correct = decUtf8.decode(bytesUtf8)
var decBytesIsoInUtf8 = decUtf8.decode(bytesIso)
var decBytesUtf8InIso = decIso.decode(bytesUtf8)
console.log('iso > iso', decBytesIsoCorrect)
console.log('utf-8 > utf-8', decBytesUtf8Correct)
console.log('iso > utf-8', decBytesIsoInUtf8)
console.log('utf-8 > iso', decBytesUtf8InIso)
```

note: can be used `iso-8859-n`

Comment: It works. But I have one question. UTF-8 covers all Unicode characters but iso-8859-2 supports the first 256 Unicode characters. So why UTF-8 can't decode this file? Is it because it is saved as ANSI format and if it is saved as UTF-8 this problem doesn't happen?

Comment: I edited my answer for this explanation